# How to return DateTimeOffset type with Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

how to return DateTimeOffset with a Linq query.
I need to get a due date from a table of type DateTimeOffset

```
public DateTimeOffset GetLastDate(Guid Id, Guid AppId)                     
{
   var q = from k in context.Inspections
           where k.Id == Id || k.AppId == AppId
           select k.Duedate;
   return q;
}
```

cannot implicitly convert system.Linq.IQueryable to System.DateTimeOffset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your query will return an `IQueryable<T>`, with the type being the type of `Duedate`.

If `Duedate` is a `DateTimeOffset`, you could return the first result (Where can return multiple matches) via:

```
    var q = from k in context.Inspections
            where k.Id== Id||k.AppId== AppId
            select k.Duedate;
    DateTimeOffset? value = q.First();

    if (value.HasValue)
        return value.Value;
    else // found NULL in DB! Do something in this case...
        throw new ApplicationException("Null offset found");

    // Alternatively, you could use some default value (this uses "Now"):
    // return value ?? DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

Comment: Better to use `.Single()` if you want to ensure that you only get one result, or to use `orderby` to control which of multiple results you get.

Comment: with this it says..cannot implicitly convert system.DateTimeOffset? to System.DateTimeOffSet....and how can i return just date

Comment: @hvd Depends on what's "Better" in this situation - very different behavior, neither is necessarily correct.

Comment: @user1016740 Your column allows for nulls, which is why you're getting that - I'll edit to show one way to handle it.

Comment: @user1016740 You should decide what's appropriate in the case of not having a value...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, my two suggestions behave differently, that's because depending on the desired behaviour, I'm suggesting to use one or the other, but pretty much never `.First()` on an unordered set.